# Typescript: generic type not correctly inferred (`unknown`)

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I'm trying to create a small system similar to Redux/Redux-toolkit. What I would like is to have a createSlice function like this:

```js
interface Lobby {
  players: string[];
}

const slice = createSlice<Lobby>({
  addPlayer: (state, name: string) => ({ ...state, players: [...players, name ] }),
});
```

It should return an object like this:

```
{
  actions: { addPlayer: (name: string) => ({ type: 'addPlayer', payload: name }) }
  reducer: (state: Lobby, action: { type: string, payload: any }) => Lobby
}
```

After experimenting I think `createSlice` cannot be implemented in this way, because it has multiple generic arguments, and you can't just partially apply only state: `Lobby` as a parameter.

The closest thing I have so far is this (actual implementation aside):

```js
const createSlice = <S, T extends Record<string, (state: S, payload: any) => S>>(
  actions: T
) => {
  type ActionsType = {
    [K in keyof T]: (
      payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1]
    ) => { type: K; payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1] };
  };

  type ReducerType = (state: S, { type: string, payload: any }) => S;

  return {
    actions: ("implementation" as any) as ActionsType,
    reducer: ("implementation" as any) as ReducerType,
  };
};
```

which I can use like this:

```
const slice = createSlice({
  addPlayer: (state: Lobby, name: string) => ({ ...state, players: [...players, name ] }),
});
```

This works, but the parameter `S` is incorrectly (?) inferred as `unknown`, so the reducer type is wrong, and the following will not cause a type error:

```
const actions = slice({
  addPlayer: (state: Lobby, name: string) => 3, // 3 is not Lobby, so I want this to error
});
```

I'm not sure how to proceed / fix this now..

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/vwjxlm) where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about; any typos should be fixed so that people who want to help can spend their time finding the solution without having to first "find the question".

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/ewevdN) meet your needs, using currying to simulate partial type parameter inference?  If not, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't entirely understand what was causing the initial problem, but factoring out generic types allows `createSlice` to take a single generic argument & seems to get things erroring properly.

```
type ActionOptions<S> = Record<string, (state: S, payload: any) => S>;
type ActionsType<S, T extends ActionOptions<S>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (
      payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1]
    ) => { type: K; payload: Parameters<T[K]>[1] };
};

type ReducerType<S> = (state: S, {type, payload}: { type: string, payload: any }) => S;

function createSlice<S> (
  actions: ActionOptions<S>
) {  
  return {
    actions: ("implementation" as any) as ActionsType<S, ActionOptions<S>>,
    reducer: ("implementation" as any) as ReducerType<S>,
  };
};

type Lobby = { __brand: 'lobby' };

const slice = createSlice({
  addPlayer: (state: Lobby, payload: string) => ({ ...state, players: [payload ] }),
});

const actions = createSlice({
  addPlayer: (state: Lobby, name: string) => 3, // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Lobby'
});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYHkxLQZwDwDKAfFALxQBKEcyATgCZ47C2KoDmANFABTMCGwCAC4oBbmH4gANsn71R-VCACUZEsQDcAKFCRYCFKhwAVcBELcTUCAA8hqejgPYMWI-mIlyAb21QAqABtAGkoNigAawgQZAAzKBMAXVEef0CAyRk5BSgABX5afgBbCCFafBNQpKIggEYk9IC1UhIfKD0RKBDNKCzZeVECotLyyurahqgAXx1p3XNKCHoAVzgIWjNIQm9eASFRcSgfTokpAfpp0XbO0WZWDjPswaglEBmWjR1tOJXUQzQUDgtAggggBGkiHWO146X4AOMongrkwrk8RG0anaUHSIOAK1oqGOTVeCJwqQARIhimBpBBSqhgIIjBTXs43mp+M5kR4thYjjy0KiPDsiJwSSDVutaJTqbT6RBGcy0Kyua9lJznFQpRs+TtxQFZtojQt9AAZZAAI0t718UAA+vbLUVHKIAOSya0gN0zb40YzAKA4SHrMhAkFgiFQiA8PwBeT0PLSKQbVL7LoWr1PC53FhsdifXjtAB0pfTEmTIA25OC-RyUCSH3F0xUftwgfhaLDwNBQij61jcPoicrqb2TIOUEzNu4qBKXXu+cLAGZuAB6NdQZfhZyoZCB6cgbg4ZBQACSUAA7kpA8AABaIZzAU8bWh0Y2t7TaIA)